# Oracle APEX 5.0: Set second Y-Axis on D3 Line Chart

Tags: d3.js, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm creating a multi-series line chart in APEX 5.0 and I've used the D3 Line Chart Plugin to do this. My output looks something like this:

[image]

I want the blue line to be on a secondary Y-axis rather than share the primary axis with the red line but can't figure out how to do it.

I looked at the [Oracle Jet Cookbook](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet-420/jetCookbook.html?component=lineChart&demo=dualY) and it says using the `assignedToY2` attribute but I can't figure out where that would go and how to use that to set a secondary y-axis.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: @AliTurabAbbasi nope, still waiting :(

Comment: I figured it out. You need to have two series. You just need to go the series you want on the secondary axis and toggle the *assigned to Y2 axis * switch. now the second series would be displayed in the secondary y-axis